# Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs is missing in Telegram.Bot v17.x.x package

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm using .NET 5.0, and have installed a pack of **Telegram.Bot v17.0.0-alpha.3**.

When I tried to write an argument as `MessageEventArgs` type I couldn't find this class. There're only two classes in the namespace `Telegram.Bot.Args`, like `ApiRequestEventArgs` and `ApiResponseEventArgs`.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MessageEventArgs` was marked as obsolete since v16.0.0 with [the following message](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/16.0.0/lib/netstandard1.1/Telegram.Bot.dll/Telegram.Bot.Args/MessageEventArgs?code=true):

> This class will be removed in the next major version. Please consider
> using Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling instead.

So, the `MessageEventArgs` [has been removed](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/commit/6838acab629a67f351cb874fea9e138db6315a11#diff-d8bf87c63953b15ce267b78ee969d25a6738bc5b607acab0d8bdcc1e86edec81) in the release of version 17.0.0-alpha.1

Comment: Thank you very much)

Answer (score 0):

After their update to 17.0.0, there are some changes. For your issue, do the following:
Instead of using:

```
MessageEventArgs e
```

Use with:

```
Update update
```

Just do not forget to add using of:

```
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
```

And of course wherever you have for example:

```
e.Message.Chat.Id
```

Change it to:

```
update.Message.Chat.Id
```

Good luck